# How to define a generic field copy function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am attempting to define a generic field copy function in TypeScript but failed to get the typing working. See method 4 in the code below. My question is, how I can write a function which can make the TypeScript typing working properly and check the destination type and source type?

Long story: I am working in a project which read data from NoSQL database and return to client via API. From security point of view, it is better to do a projection (explicit field copy) to avoid any future addition of fields returned to client. I am looking for an easy way to do this.

```
// ----------
// TypeScript type definition
// ----------
interface Student {
  name: string
  studentId?: string
}

interface StudentDbRecord extends Student {
  createTimestamp: number
}

interface StudentApiResult extends Student {
  // We use NoSQL, so ID is not part of the record
  id: string
}

// ----------
// Database data
// ----------
const docId: string = '6542fdba-fcae-4b15-a1c8-72a2a57f51c7'
const dbRecord: StudentDbRecord = {
  name: 'Chirs',
  createTimestamp: Date.now()
}

// ----------
// Implementation
// ----------
// Method 1: An extra `createTimestamp` field is in `apiResult1` and returned to API caller
const apiResult1: StudentApiResult = {
  ...dbRecord,
  id: docId
}

const apiResult2: StudentApiResult = {
  id: docId,
  name: dbRecord.name,
  // Method 2: This result in a field with `undefined` value, which causes other issues
  studentId: dbRecord.studentId
}

// Method 3: This works, but easier to make mistake because `studentId` is specified 3 times
const apiResult3: StudentApiResult = {
  id: docId,
  name: dbRecord.name
}
if (dbRecord.studentId !== null) { apiResult3.studentId = dbRecord.studentId }

// Method 4, this should be the best but unable to get it working in TypeScript
function copyField<D, S, K extends (keyof D & keyof S)>(dest: D, src: S, key: K): void {
  if (src[key] !== undefined) {
    // Error ts(2322): 'D' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'S'
    dest[key] = src[key]
  }
}

const apiResult4: StudentApiResult = {
  id: docId,
  name: dbRecord.name
}
copyField(apiResult4, dbRecord, 'studentId')
```

Comment: You would really benefit from focusing on creating a minimal reproducible example... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I did it for you https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiAbgUzgLgCIgOYwLwwDeAUDGTABYCGEAYgDbI1pRwCuyANKedRAMpQAlsADWaAGZV6EZMQC+xYqEiwJyekIAeaAMJVYBEuUo0GTCJOmzuJvgFkQbWS3ZzFykAAcAnrSEaACYAFAgocJzqmlqcAER85jSxAJQA3EpCYFCoUsDIMFi4xrxmjMwARiAgZWA8ZHyCIuKV1Uy1HpnZcLn5+rDF9aUWaC01daYQjs7II1VjHhJsYMDC4DCgvv5BADwYnDD8+wDSMMha2WCBEDDBosg+IBIFMABkMHcPT-zJAHzBgchoGgCvsIHBgMDDu97sCjslgYgQEJAkQeEInsEwcAANofAC6MAAhHgCEsARJMshAslUSYAPR0mAAUTgCDgMCgEGCACYAMzc7nwmAAcgwwvWTnoKPK+Uy0CoWSEBipMAA7kIoBQYArtXByhq4FQ4D4OT4vPlVRQRFrQGwpTAZTAlnANMqUVAQCL+MLxgDoLj7gSCFiAz48TxFPIgA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to only commit to the minimal typings for the inbound dest and src objects. See the minimal repro I made for you and a potential solution at [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=38&pc=2#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)

```
function copyField<Key extends keyof any, Value>(
  key: Key,
  source: { [K in Key]: Value },
  dest: { [K in Key]: Value }
): void {
  const sourceValue = source[key];
  if (sourceValue !== undefined) {
    dest[key] = sourceValue;
  }
}

const rover: Dog = {
  hasFleas: true,
  hasStick: false,
};

const felix: Cat = {
  hasFleas: false,
  hasMouse: true,
};

const klaus: Fish = {
  hasTeeth: false,
};

copyField("hasFleas", rover, felix);

//this is (correctly) a compiler error
copyField("hasFleas", felix, klaus);

interface Dog {
  hasFleas: boolean;
  hasStick: boolean;
}

interface Cat {
  hasFleas: boolean;
  hasMouse: boolean;
}

interface Fish {
  hasTeeth: boolean;
}
```